# Missing some block fields

Tags: 8, layout-builder

I'm working with layout_builder and page_manager together and I'm having some issues.

I want to add an existing node to my right sidebar, but I don't see the option anywhere where I can do that.

In D7, all I have to do is click the gear icon > click existing node > add the node ID. Done!

Does anyone know what I have to do?

Thank you!

This is all I see

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out layout_builder doesn't provide you an option to do it. I found this module that lets you do it. https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_block

Hope this helps anyone who has the same issue as me.